# output list of unique random numbers from string

Tags: php

I have a set of numbers that i get from an html form eg: `123456`

I would like to output x amount of unique random numbers eg: `143256` `312456` `453216` etc

I have searched and searched and can not find how to do this.

I am using this code to shuffle the original number but do not understand how to create a loop to output x amount of lines.

```
$numbers = array("$n1","$n2","$n3","$n4","$n5","$n6");
shuffle($numbers);
foreach ($numbers as $v) {
    echo = "$v ";
}
```

Could someone give me a tip and point me in the right direction
your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Kinda unsure what you're looking for but if you just want them separated by a line break just put one before the last quote in the echo.

Answer (score 0):

In order to generate a random number in PHP you can use a function called ['mt_rand()'](https://www.php.net/mt_rand)

This function will return a number between a min and max range.

In order to get a random sized list of random numbers you could simply..

```
// Random numbers array
$randomNumbers = array();

// Create a random sized array between 1 and 30 values in length.
for($x = 0; $x < mt_rand(1,30); $x++) {
    // Generate a random number and push it onto the array.
    $randomNumbers[] = mt_rand(0, 99999);
}

// display the generated numbers
print_r($randomNumbers);
die();
```

In order to make the list of numbers unique you can perform a check when the number is generated to see if it is in the list of numbers. You can do this using [in_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

I'm not sure if this answers your question, hopefully it will.

Comment: It looks like user3230552 wants to create random numbers made from only the digits provided.

Comment: 'x amount of unique random numbers eg: 143256 312456 453216' this made me unsure. It left with the impression that he wanted to also generate the unique random number.

Comment: Yeah, it took me a moment to get it.  Notice that each example given contains all of the digits 1 2 3 4 5 6.

Comment: Almost sounds like he should be doing the swapping manually with switch values and shifting left to get all unique combinations. Would be faster than shuffling the values and checking uniqueness over large iterations.

Comment: sorry for being unclear in the original post it is hard for me to explain Calebj i think has the correct method I need but switch values and shifting spun my head around twice.

Answer (score 0):

use a [for loop](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php)

```
<?php
$numbers=array("$n1","$n2","$n3","$n4","$n5","$n6");

$howManyRandomNumbers = 10; // This is how many you want.
for ($i = 1; $i <= $howManyRandomNumbers; $i++) {
    shuffle($numbers);
    foreach($numbers as $v) {
        echo "$v ";
    }
}
?>
```

Note that this will NOT produce UNIQUE numbers, just random ones.

Answer (score 0):

[Another attempt](http://codepad.org/ZZGq6vDL):

```
$n1 = rand(100000,999999);
$n2 = rand(100000,999999);
$n3 = rand(100000,999999);
$n4 = rand(100000,999999);
$n5 = rand(100000,999999);
$n6 = rand(100000,999999);
$numbers = array($n1,$n2,$n3,$n4,$n5,$n6);

function code ($numbers)
{
    $code = "";
    foreach($numbers as $n)
    {
        $n .= ""; // turn $n into a string
        $code .= $n[rand(0,strlen($n)-1)];
    }
    return $code;
}

echo "numbers:\n";
foreach($numbers as $n) echo "$n\n";

echo "\ncodes:\n";
for ($i = 0 ; $i != 10 ; $i++) echo code ($numbers)."\n";
```

Comment: Thanks for the feed back.. i am using a form or user inputted number the idea is i enter x amount of numbers into the form and php creates an array of those specific numbers then outputs x amount of unique random lines based on the original input .. its kinda hard to explain.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you wanted this?

```
<?php
    $numbers=array($n1,$n2,$n3,$n4,$n5,$n6");
    for($i=0;$i<=10;$i++) {
        shuffle($numbers);
        foreach($numbers as $v) {
            echo $v;
        }
        echo "<br />\r\n";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    $numbers  = array($n1,$n2,$n3,$n4,$n5,$n6);
    shuffle($numbers);
    foreach(array_slice(array_unique($numbers), $start,$limit) as $v)
       echo $v." ";
```

---

You have checkboxes of n1 to n24 with unique values so saying you want "unique random numbers" was confusing.

Now i recommend you change your 
`<input name="n..." value="$value">` to `<input name="n[]" value="$value">` Then put this in your php

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $limit2 = $_POST["limit2"];
    $limit  = $_POST['limit'];

    /*
     *  Since you have input fields of n1 to n24 i put them in an array
     */
    $n  = array();
    if(isset($_POST['n'])){
        foreach($_POST['n'] as $key=>$value)
            $n[$key] = $value;  
        shuffle($n);
    }

    /*
     *  All your checkbox values are unique so i don't get what you mean by "unique values"
     */
    for($x = 0, $y = count($n) - 1; $x = 0; $x++,$y--) {

        $v = preg_replace(array('/\s{2,}/', '/[\t\n]/'), ' ', $n[$x]);

            echo $v ."
\r\n";

    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: when i use this code foreach(array_slice(array_unique($numbers), 0,1) as $v) it gives some strange results sometimes it throws out 2 numbers instead of a single. but works perfect for any number over 1. sometimes the output is also not unique i get duplicated results.

Comment: Are you using it together with the for loop you provided 7 hours ago? try 
        `$numbers = array($n1,$n2,$n3,$n4,$n5,$n6);
        $numbers = array_unique($numbers);
        shuffle($numbers);
        $numbers = array_slice($numbers, $start,$limit);
        foreach($numbers as $number)
           echo $number." ";`
And don't nest it in a for loop

Comment: Hi meLove, you can tell i am not much of a coder the complete source code is at toplinetransport.com.au/vin/index.phps i am trying the new answer now. you could get a better idea of what i am trying to do if you view the phps and the php file. thanks for the help i really appreciate it.

Comment: Check my edit, hope this helps but I don't understand what $limit is for but that should give you a better idea

Comment: i couldn't get it to work like that :( here is an image that may clarify what i am trying to do ... http://postimg.org/image/5xowxbi7n/

Answer (score 0):

**Take this:**

```
echo = "$v ";
```

**And make it this:**

```
echo "$v 
";
```

This will give you a new line after every number.

## [Live Demo :)](http://codepad.org/4mos81Ki)

Answer (score 0):

WOW Thanks for the input peoples!

Using the answers provided i have the code working nearly exactly how i wanted it :)

```
<?php
$numbers = array(
    "$n1",
    "$n2",
    "$n3",
    "$n4",
    "$n5"
);
for ($i = 0; $i <= $limit; $i++) {
    shuffle($numbers);
    foreach (array_slice(array_unique($numbers), 0, $limit2) as $v) {
        echo $v;
    }
    echo "<br />\r\n";
}
?>
```

Regards,